# Implementing a for loop of share prices

Tags: python, loops

I need to work out a value S(n) based on the equation

```
s(n) = (1 + r(1))(1+r(2))...(1+r(n))
```

The value of

```
S(after N days) = (1+r(after 1 day))*(1+r(after 2 days))...(1+r(after N days))
```

with r coming from:

```
r = return_daily + sig_daily
```

but calculated D times (see code below, D is calculated once for each day and is a random value)

I'm just not too sure how to implement the equation including a changing variable(r changes daily).

Thanks for any help

Relevant Code:

```
#import all modules required
import numpy as np # using different notation for easier writting
import scipy as sp 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

#collect variables provided by the user

period = 63 # can be edited to an input() command for variable periods.
Return_annual = np.arange(0.00,0.15,0.05) # creates an array ??? not sure if helpful
sig_annual = np.arange(0.01,0.31,0.01) #use .31 as python doesnt include the upper range value.


#functions for variables of daily return and risk.

Return_daily = (1/252)*R_annual
sig_daily = (1/(np.sqrt(252)))*sig_annual

D=np.random.normal(size=period)

r_i=Return_daily + sig_daily # must be calculated D times
```

Comment: We're not sure how to implement it either without some more information. Please read [ask] and try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I haven't got a functioning code, but i'll add the relevant non-working parts. Sorry if the question asked is bad, I'm so stuck im not sure what to ask to solve how to write the equation properly

Answer (score 0):

How do you receive your inputs?

you can receive them one by one and append them to a meta list, and then you can use a function where you pass your list of r(n) and output whatever you want.

for example if you want geometrically linked returns:

```
rors=[0.4, 0.5, 0.8]

#calculate compound return
def calc_ror(ror_list):
    final_value=0
    for i in ror_list:
        final_value=(1+i)*(1+final_value)-1
    return final_value

calc_ror(rors)
Out[35]: 2.7799999999999994
```

Another cool trick is using variable input arguments, in that case each argument in the function is a different return.

```
#calculate compound return
def calc_ror(*args):
    final_value=0
    for i in args:
        final_value=(1+i)*(1+final_value)-1
    return final_value

calc_ror(0.4, 0.5, 0.8)
Out[37]: 2.7799999999999994
```

Or finally using pandas

```
import pandas as pd

rors=[0.4, 0.5, 0.8]
df = pd.DataFrame(rors, columns=['ror'])
df_cum=pd.DataFrame((1 + df['ror']).cumprod()-1)

df_cum.tail(1)
Out[42]: 
ror
2  2.78
```

I hope one of these alternatives applies to your case